# Starting Rscript with Java ProcessBuilder (under Windows)

Tags: java, r, processbuilder, rscript

I did a Java-project, that runs normally under Linux and in that project I start a ProcessBuild with

```
new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "Rscript scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

... where the "scriptname" and the "args" ofcourse are some Strings.
Anyway it worked very well for me: The script is loaded with the 3 args.

Now I had to run the whole project under Windows. There occured a lot of problems as well and the last open problem is the start of Rscript (now Rscript.exe) with the specific script and the args.

Therefore I tried several things out like

```
new ProcessBuilder(".../Rscript.exe scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

or

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", ".../Rscript.exe scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3" );
```

and other combinations from that.

I am really now pro with R and no pro with starting things from Windows-console at all.

Can anyone help me with that?
I think the only problem is the correct call, or the correct migration from that call under Linux to a call under Windows.

Comment: Did you try `new ProcessBuilder(".../Rscript.exe","scriptname","arg1","arg2","arg3")`? This should work since `Rscript.exe` is your command and `scriptname`,`arg1`,...,`argn` are parameters to this command.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I tried this but not working.